# Filtering in data frame and replace string with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, null, nan

I wanted to filter for fruits containing %G% or %P%
if not like %G% or %P% then should be replaced as NaN

| Unique ID | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Banana | Peach | Guava |
| 1235 | Orange | Grape | NaN |
| 1236 | Pear | Papaya | Apricot |
| 1237 | Guava | NaN | NaN |
| 1238 | Kiwi | Cherry | Peach |

My result would need to look like:

| Unique ID | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | NaN | Peach | Guava |
| 1235 | NaN | Grape | NaN |
| 1236 | Pear | Papaya | NaN |
| 1237 | Guava | NaN | NaN |
| 1238 | NaN | NaN | Peach |

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change only certain columns, you can do this:

```py
to_replace = ["Fruit1", "Fruit2", "Fruit3"]  # these columns will be changed
for column in to_replace:
    df[column] = df[column].where(
        df[column].str.contains("G|P")
    )
```

By default, `str.contains` uses regex, so it might be a bit more convenient if you are familiar with regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a list with the strings to match
to_search = ["G","P"]
# Replaces string by np.NaN if it doesnt contain any "G" or "P" 
rep = lambda string: np.nan if not any(s in string for s in to_search) else string
# Apply the function to the whole DataFrame
df = df.applymap(rep)
```

This should do the trick, assuming that your DataFrame is called df.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) the "fruit" columns, then use a regex to [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the values that don't start with P or G:

```
cols = list(df.filter(like='Fruit'))
# ['Fruit1', 'Fruit2', 'Fruit3']

out = (df.drop(columns=cols)
         .join(df[cols].replace('^(?![PG])', np.nan, regex=True))
         [df.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
   Unique ID Fruit1  Fruit2 Fruit3
0       1234    NaN   Peach  Guava
1       1235    NaN   Grape    NaN
2       1236   Pear  Papaya    NaN
3       1237  Guava     NaN    NaN
4       1238    NaN     NaN  Peach
```